# Kernel killed while there is plenty of available RAM

Tags: python, linux-kernel, ram, comm

I am running a python program transforming all the .png files in a folder to a gif with the following code:

```
    import glob
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

# filepaths
fp_in = path_monthly + '/' + "*.png"
fp_out = path_directory + '/' + "Monthly_MB.gif"

# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in sorted(glob.glob(fp_in))]
img.save(fp=fp_out, format='GIF', append_images=imgs,
         save_all=True, duration=600, loop=0)


import glob
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

# filepaths
fp_in = path_yearly + '/'  + "*.png"
fp_out = path_directory + '/' + "Yearly_MB.gif"

# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in sorted(glob.glob(fp_in))]
img.save(fp=fp_out, format='GIF', append_images=imgs,
         save_all=True, duration=600, loop=0)
```

There are 193 png files, the total weight is 500Mb. My laptop has 16Gb of RAM. However, when I run the program, the kernel is automatically killed and restarted and displays:

Restarting kernel...

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 25562a62516411ebbc72f17b9468ff8d

How come this program seems to use all the RAM of my laptop ? I am running on a dual-boot, with plenty enough storage and no other major program running in the background other than spyder. Do you have an idea why this kind of problem appears ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you use a 64bit OS or 32bit OS?

Comment: I use a 64bit OS. I also ran it on a server that managed to make it run when nobody was using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I google the problem, and find the answer. Lots of people meet the problem, and in [github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11965) the suggestion is

> Please update to Spyder 4.1.4. This problem should be fixed in that version.

And some people said it has been solved - needed to add the extended dependencies for QT. I think that link can help you solve your problem.